# How to make Bootstrap 'List group' responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using  Bootstrap '[List group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-basic)' and I need to make it responsive. 
Means in mobile view, The list would show as a drop down button like navbar.

I tried nav classes, But not working as expected.
Code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#side-menu-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>    
<ul class="list-group collapse navbar-collapse" id="#side-menu-collapse">
  <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of media query. In overiding the `collapse` class when the screen size is different of `XS`.

**Bootply** : https://www.bootply.com/L5BYCOwsZG

**CSS** :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {  
    .custom-collapse .collapse {
            display:block;
    }  
}
```

**HTML** :

```
<div class="custom-collapse">
  <button class="collapse-toggle visible-xs " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="custom-collapse" data-target="#side-menu-collapse">
      <span class="">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button> 
  <ul class="list-group collapse" id="side-menu-collapse">
    <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item dropdown-toggle">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add `visibility: visible;` in the css